# how to use xsl to distinguish two similar tags (variables)

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to create a xsl able to read two xml files, which have the same structure except by the first tag:

inbound xml:

```
<beans:beans> <fix-inbound> <message></message> </fix-inbound> </beans:beans>
```

outbound xml:

```
<beans:beans> <fix-outbound> <message></message> </fix-outbound> </beans:beans>
```

the solutions I could find out were:

- creating two files to read the inbound and outbound
- an awful if like :

  ```
  <xsl:if test="fix-inbound">
      code to read the content
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="fix-outbound"> 
      same piece of code to read the content 
  </xsl:if>
  ```
- using a variable in my   `<xsl:for-each select="$valueOfMyFirstTag">` which the value of the variable could be **fix-inbound** or **fix-outbound**

However, I have no idea how to get the value of the first tag. Is that possible using xsl?

Is there a more elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: What value are you trying to get? Are you trying to print the value of `message` using a template that handles both possible parent elements?

Comment: It's not clear why you are concern about this? Do you need an XPath expression to select inner elements? It looks like you are suffering the consequence of a push style processing. Provide desired output for both of your input samples.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a simple and short way to accomplish the desired processing with absolutely no conditional XSLT instructions. Welcome to the power and elegance of XSLT.

Comment: @lwburk : I was using a for-each to navigate in my xml structure as follows : <xsl:for-each select="beans:beans/fix-inbound/message">, but now my xml can have: beans:beans/ fix-inbound or fix-outbound / message . I don't know how to make , using a variable or an expression, the for-each accept this new option in that xml level

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
<xsl:for-each select="/*/fix-inbound | /*/fix-outbound">
```

(or depending on your use case, use `apply-templates` instead of `for-each`).

Answer (score 1):

It's not at all clear what you are trying to do or where you are failing, but it does appear from your post that you haven't yet discovered the joy of template rules, which form the heart of true XSLT processing. Perhaps you also haven't yet discovered the power of wildcards (*) in paths, or the "//" pseudo-operator.

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*[1]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fix-inbound">
 <!-- Perform whatever processing is necessary  -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fix-outbound">
 <!-- Perform whatever processing is necessary  -->
</xsl:template>
```

**Explanation**:

The `<xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*[1]"/>` instruction causes whatever template best matches the first child element of the top element to be selected for execution and applied.

If the document is of the first type, the template matching `fix-inbound` is applied.

If the document is of the second type, the template matching `fix-outbound` is applied.

**Do note:** No conditional instructions are used at all in this solution -- in XSLT they are rarely necessary and if conditional instructions are present, this is a signal that some refactoring may be appropriate.